# Hackerearth Feel Taller

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Link to the problem -> https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/feel-taller/

What is wrong with my code or logic?

I keep track of the number of building taller than the current building starting from the last building using **STACK**. I do this by keeping track of number of elements in the stack(the elements which are taller than the current element).

In the queries i subtract the left from right and add 1.
left -> number of building that can be seen from left
right -> number of building that can be seen from right
If we subtract both we get number of building than can be seen in the range.

Consider an example: There are 7 pillars (k) and height of each pillar is 5 2 3 7 9 8 11. Using stack I keep track of number of pillars greater than the current pillar (so visible over it) and store it in array p . Whose values are (height of the current pillar)->(number of pillars greater than this pillar) 5->3 2->4 3->3 7->2 9->1 8->1 11->0 . In the queries i subtract right from left because left has the number of pillars greater than the current pillar and if i subtract right i get the pillars in range.

**I want to know what is wrong with this logic.**

There is a different approach for the problem and i know that.
*Please tell me what is wrong with this code.*

**Link to my code** -> https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/42773897/

```
//https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/feel-taller/
//Feel Taller
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Feel_Taller{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine().trim());

        long a[] = new long[k];
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
            a[i] = Long.parseLong(st.nextToken());

        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        int n = 0;                              //Number of elements in the stack
        int p[] = new int[k];                   //Number of pillars greater than this pillar

        for(int i = k-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            while(!s.empty() && a[s.peek()]<=a[i]){
                s.pop();
                n--;
            }
            p[i] = n;
            s.push(i);
            n++;
        }

        //Queries
        int q = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        while(q-->0){
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine().trim());
            int l = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int r = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            if(r>=k)
                r = k-1;
            sb.append(p[l]-p[r]+1).append("\n");
        }

        pw.print(sb);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Or please explain how can we solve the problem using my approach.
Thank you.

Comment: Consider a example  : There are 7 pillars (k)   and height of each pillar is 5 2 3 7 9 8 11 .   Using stack I keep track of number of pillars greater than the current pillar and store it in array p .  Whose values are (height of the current pillar)->(number of pillars greater than this pillar)    5->3  2->4  3->3  7->2  9->1  8->1  11->0 .   In the queries i subtract right from left because left has the number of pillars greater than the current pillar and if i subtract right i get the pillars in range.

Comment: If you hang around for more Stack Overflow question (which I hope): Supplying additional information and explanation is welcome. Please add it in the question itself, not as a comment. It’s good to have everything in one place, and many users won’t read through the comments.

Comment: Thank u for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having studied your code, this is where your logic seems to go wrong: your subtraction will not always give the correct result.

Consider this row of buildings or pillars:

```
7 3 5
```

Now I believe that your counts of taller pillars should be 7->0 3->1 and 5->0.

When I query the range [0, 1] the answer should be 1: only the 7 tall building is visible. Your subtraction `p[l]-p[r]+1` yields 0 - 1 + 1 = 0, so one building too few. One way to put it is, you subtract 1 for the 5 tall building because it is outside the queried range, but that building was never visible in the first place so should not be subtracted.

Comment: Thanks a lot       I messed up the logic 